# the right way to introduce a vivid recollection in English

Tags: phrase-request

What's the right way to introduce a vivid recollection that you are about to share? This way looks kind of broken to me:

> As for his overall performance this year, **here I especially have one
> vivid memory of him how** he once participated in a small skit. That
> was just fantastic! He was able then to show all of his main abilities in...

The usage of the word "here" in my example seems to be redundant. The phrase "I especially have" also most probably sounds rather awkward (How can you have something especially? You either have something, or you don't have it). Also, I am not sure that "of him how" is a correct usage as well.

So, based on this and comments below, should I reduce the paragraph to:

> As for his overall performance this year, **I have one
> vivid memory of him:** how he once participated in a small skit. That
> was just fantastic! He was able then to show all of his main abilities in...

Comment: At the moment this is off-topic, as it is asking for something to be corrected. Can you explain WHY you think it is wrong? In doing so you might answer your own question, but if you can ask a question about why you are still confused after research, you might have a valid question.

Comment: What is problematic for you?  I might put some punctuation (maybe a colon) after "him".  To show that the word "how" is part of the following phrase. But why should "I have one vivid memory" be a broken way to say that you have a vivid memory!?

Comment: @Astralbee - (1) Had I been asking for something to be corrected, my question would have sounded something like "Is this way of saying correct?" or "Is this ok to say like this?" But my question was and still is "What's the right way to introduce...?" I just came up with this example to illustrate the thought that I want to express, and in no way am I asking to correct that example. As to "why I think it is wrong", well, first of all, I didn't say it was wrong. I said "it looks broken" to me.

Comment: @Astralbee - (2) Why? Because I concocted it very quickly and based on the grammar of my first language, which in 99 cases out of 100 results in the thought being conveyed, yet conveyed in a very "broken", that is, unnatural and not idiomatic way. For example, the usage of the word "here" in my example seems to be redundant. The phrase "I especially have" also most probably sounds rather awkward (How can you have something especially? You either have something, or you don't have it). Also, I am not sure that "of him how" is a correct usage as well.

Comment: @JamesK - The usage of the word "here" in my example seems to be redundant. The phrase "I especially have" also most probably sounds rather awkward (How can you especially have something? You either have something, or you don't have it). Also, I am not sure that "of him how" is a correct usage as well. Besides, there may be nothing wrong with my example, however, it may still not sound the way native speakers would express that thought if they were to do that. What I want to know is how a native speaker would go about a similar situation.

Comment: Well I've incorporated the suggestions in the comments for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding redundant words is a matter of style and choice. Some native speakers revel in redundancy and some try to cut it out completely.  If you feel that a word doesn't add to what you are saying, cut it out.

The word "how" belongs to the phrase "how he once performed..."  it introduces a content clause.  It's good to use some punctuation to mark this division.  And in speech you would mark this by rhythmic and intonational patterns, (eg a slight pause after "him".)

The meaning should be consistent.  This is not about English, but any language.  The opening tell us you will describe "his overall performance", but the rest speaks only about one specific event. That's inconsistent, but it is a flaw in the writing, not the English.